# Finding $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{243}{16(n\pi )^5}\sin(2n\pi /3)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, residue-calculus

The WolfarmAlpha couldn't give me the sum of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{243}{16(n\pi )^5}\sin(2n\pi /3)$$ therefore I thought that this problem is difficult so I used my calculator to get $(1/24)$

Is this value right or not?
If this right, why the WolfarmAlph couldn't find it?

Comment: Wait, your calculator could sum this up whist WolframAlpha could not?! What brand of calculator are you using?

Comment: Casio Super-FX PLUS $5800P$

Comment: Trivial for Srinivasa Ramanujan :P

Comment: Factor all constants outside of the actual sum, and break the series into three subseries, then use the known values for the [Dirichlet $\beta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).

Comment: Why the heck are all the current answers getting a downvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\displaystyle\sin{\frac{2 n \pi}{3}}}{n^5} $$

This sum is a bit easier than it looks, if you know the residue theorem.  The main observation is that the numerator either takes the value $\sqrt{3}/2$, $-\sqrt{3}/2$, or $0$.  Then you may rewrite the sum as

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [\frac1{(3 n-2)^5} - \frac1{(3 n-1)^5}\right ] = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4 \cdot 3^5} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \left [\frac1{(n-2/3)^5} - \frac1{(n-1/3)^5}\right ]$$

We may apply the residue theorem to this sum by considering the following result:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = -\pi \sum_k \operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_k} [ \cot{\pi z} \, f(z) ]$$

where $z_k$ are the non-integer poles of $f$.  All we need to do is compute the residues at the poles, which in this case are at $z=1/3$ and $z=2/3$.  For example,

$$\begin{align}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=2/3} \left [ \cot{\pi z} \, \left ((z-2/3)^{-5}-(z-1/3)^{-5}  \right ) \right] &= \frac1{4!} \left [\frac{d^4}{dz^4} \cot{\pi z}   \right ]_{z=2/3} - \frac1{4!} \left [\frac{d^4}{dz^4} \cot{\pi z}   \right ]_{z=1/3} \\ &= -\frac{8\pi^4}{3 \sqrt{3}}\end{align}$$

The sum is then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\displaystyle\sin{\frac{2 n \pi}{3}}}{n^5} = \frac{2 \pi^5}{729}$$

The result follows.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{243 \over 16\pars{n\pi}^{5}}\,\sin\pars{2n\pi \over 3}}
={243 \over 16\pi^{5}}\,\Im\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}^{n} \over n^{5}}
={243 \over 16\pi^{5}}\,\color{#c00000}{\Im\Li{5}\pars{\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Li{s}\pars{z}}$ is the [PolyLogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) .

> With [Jonquiere Inversion Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions)
>   $\ds{\Li{n}\pars{\expo{2\pi\ic x}} + \pars{-1}^{n}\Li{n}\pars{\expo{-2\pi\ic x}}
> =-\,{\pars{2\pi\ic}^{n} \over n!}\,\,{\rm B}_{n}\pars{x}}$ where
>   $\ds{\,{\rm B}_{n}\pars{x}}$ is a
>   [Bernoulli Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials) we'll have:
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#c00000}{\Im\Li{5}\pars{\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}}
> &={\Li{5}\pars{\expo{2\pi\ic/3}} - \Li{5}\pars{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}} \over 2\ic}
> =-\pi\,{\pars{2\pi\ic}^{4} \over 5!}\,\,{\rm B}_{5}\pars{1 \over 3}
> \\[5mm]&=\color{#c00000}{-\,{2\pi^{5} \over 15}\,\,{\rm B}_{5}\pars{1 \over 3}}
> \end{align}
>   [Note that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Explicit_expressions_for_low_degrees)
>   $\ds{\,{\rm B}_{5}\pars{x}=
>      x^{5} - {5 \over 2}\,x^{4} + {5 \over 3}\,x^{3} - {1 \over 6}\,x}$ such that
>   $\ds{\color{#c00000}{\,{\rm B}_{5}\pars{1 \over 3} = -\,{5 \over 243}}}$.

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{243 \over 16\pars{n\pi}^{5}}\,\sin\pars{2n\pi \over 3}}
={243 \over 16\pi^{5}}\bracks{\pars{-\,{2\pi^{5} \over 15}}\pars{-\,{5 \over 243}}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 24}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

We have the following identity for Polylogarithm function:
[$$\text{Li}_n(e^{2 \pi i x}) + (-1)^n\text{Li}_n(e^{-2 \pi i x}) = - \dfrac{(2 \pi i)^n}{n!} B_n(x)$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions)
where $B_n(x)$ are the [Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Explicit_expressions_for_low_degrees).
In your case, it is easy to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(nx)}{n^5} = \dfrac1{2i} \left(\text{Li}_5(e^{ix}) - \text{Li}_5(e^{-ix})\right) = -\dfrac1{2i} \dfrac{(2 \pi i)^5}{5!} B_5\left(\frac{x}{2\pi} \right) = -\dfrac{2 \pi^5}{15}B_5\left(\dfrac{x}{2\pi} \right)$$
Plugging in $x = \frac{2 \pi}3$, we obtain
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(2n\pi/3)}{n^5} = -\dfrac{2 \pi^5}{15}B_5\left(\frac13 \right) = -\dfrac{2 \pi^5}{15} \cdot \dfrac{-5}{243} = \dfrac{2 \pi^5}{729}$$

Answer (score 0):

WolframAlpha thinks that the answer can be written as polylogarithm functions:
[image: WolframAlpha 1]

It also equals to 1/24:
[image: WolframAlpha 2]

Comment: how you know this equal to $1/24$

Comment: The first result is just the definition of $Li_n(z)$; it's the fact that it's equal to $1/24$ that's the nontrivial part.

Answer (score 0):

In Maple 18:

```
S:= Sum(243/16/(n*Pi)^5*sin(2*n*Pi/3),n=1..infinity):
simplify(value(convert(S,exp)));
```

$$ \dfrac{1}{24} $$

Comment: This should have been a comment!

Comment: @Integrator I disagree. This answer is indeed answering the question as it is written: "*Is this value right or not?*"

Comment: Sorry @Venus didn't read! +1 For that!